# What is the shortest way to switch between heads of nested functions

Tags: functions

consider this example:

```
f[g[x]]
```

what is the shortest way to switch between heads of nested functions to produce.

```
g[f[x]]
```

Comment: `Thread[f[g[x]], g]`

Comment: Shortest?  Like Code Golf?  Perhaps you should tag this as such if that is what you mean.

Comment: As you wish, posted an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For your particular example,

```
Thread[f[g[x]], g]
```

Generally, we can think of `Thread` as of a function to exchange heads between first two levels. For more complex rearrangements, you may need to use replacement rules and other methods, described in other answers.

Comment: @Algohi Thanks for the accept :)

Answer (score 6):

```
#[[0]] /@ #[[1]] &@ f[g[x]]

(* g[f[x]] *)
```

Answer (score 5):

Taking the problem a bit more generally we might use a decomposition function:

```
de[p : a_@_ | _] := {a, ## & @@ de @@ p}
```

Then on  any expression with one argument at each level:

```
b[c[d[e[x]]]] // de
```

> ```
> {b, c, d, e, x}
> ```

Reorder however we please:

```
%[[{3,1,4,2,5}]]
```

> ```
> {d, b, e, c, x}
> ```

And put it back together:

```
Compose @@ %
```

> ```
> d[b[e[c[x]]]]
> ```

Answer (score 4):

What about

```
switch[f_[g_[x_]]] := f[g[x]] /. {f -> g, g -> f}
```

[image]

Comment: In your approach, you don't need an extra step with `/.`. You can simply use `switch[f_[g_[x__]]]:=g[f[x]]`. I was thinking about this method too, but there are many ways to generalize from here, and the OP didn't provide a general example / request.

Comment: Yeah, the rule is redundant, but it can remind to use replacements if it is neccessary.
Your answer with `Thread` looks very compact and natural, but it took me some time to get how it's working.

Comment: The problem is that the OP didn't formulate his general needs. There are many ways to solve this problem, which would all give the same result for his example, but will generally behave differently. Re: Thread - one good place to read on it is Wagner's book.

Answer (score 1):

```
Distribute[f[g[x]], g]
(* g[f[x]] *)
```